# Restrict an emailed URL to work only for the intended recipient

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to email a registration invite and would like to ensure that the link does not work for anyone other than the original recipient i.e. if the link is forwarded it would not work.  How could I go about this?

I haven't any idea how to accomplish this...so any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Two ideas occur to me: email verification or one-time use tokens, you can search about those and I think you can find something to start working with.